# How to trigger a SharePoint 2010 workflow from a SharePoint 2013 workflow and log to the same history list

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow-manager-1.x

I want to use approval,feedback and assign to do item processes from within WF2010, while logging all of workflows activity to the same history list (the one that WF2013 uses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the activity **InvokeSharePointWorkflow** to call a 2010 workflow from your 2013 workflow. Unfortunately the 2010 workflow will not write to the same history list the 2013 workflow uses, but from within the 2013 workflow you can reach into the 2010 history list and duplicate those items in the 2013 history list after the 2010 workflow completes (I've done this a number of times and it works just fine)

Comment: I did something similar to what you said. I created a custom list for history activity and manually 'create item' in it for each data log entry. Then I was able to create a custom view to filter on document name passed via URL.